# Adding a gif to a markdown file

Tags: markdown, gif

I added a gif to a markdown file using the following line: ! [] (link)

The image can be seen but the image is not moving and it remains a still image. Any ideas on what it could be?

Comment: Which Markdown processor are you using? How are you viewing it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<img src="yourgif.gif" align="left"/>` in markdown as well and that appears as a gif.